# combine left join into my queries but failed

Tags: php, mysql

Tried to combine another query to my existing queries but failed.

Here is the working query without LEFT JOIN

```
$order_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX .
"order_items WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
```

Below is the one tried to combined (not working)

```
$order_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX .
"order_items WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'" LEFT JOIN .
DB_PREFIX ."item_description WHERE item_id= '" . (int)$item_id . "'"
);
```

Any idea where did i do wrong ?

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN x ... WHERE x =` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct the join statement correctly. The `WHERE` clauses come in later.

```
$prefix = DB_PREFIX;
$sql = "
    SELECT oi.* FROM {$prefix}order_items AS oi
    LEFT JOIN {$prefix}item_description AS itd
    ON oi.item_id = itd.item_id
    WHERE oi.order_id = ?
    AND itd.item_id = ?
";


$this->db->query($sql, [$order_id, $item_id]);
```

Comment: Hi , i would like to know for the "?" what should i pit  ? or i leave it there ?

Comment: @Micho don't directly inject your values in the actual query, the answer above is called query bindings, the question marks are called placeholders, try the answer above

Comment: This is an INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
$order_query = $this->db->query("SELECT oi.* FROM " . DB_PREFIX ."order_items  oi
               LEFT JOIN ".DB_PREFIX ."item_description des on oi.order_id = des.order_id
               WHERE oi.order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' and  
               des.item_id= '" . (int)$item_id . "'");
```